# How to let ``make`` aware of changes in other directories?

Tags: c++, makefile, dependencies, cython

In making a `make` file in a Cython test code, I need to let `make` to notice the changes made in C++ header files stored in other directories. So I came up with the following `make` file

```
CC=python3

compile: setup.py test.pyx test.pxd test.cpp ../source/test_source.cpp ../headers/test_header.h
    $(CC) setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

The directories are structured as follows

```
/cython
    Makefile
    test.pyx
    test.pxd
    test.cpp
    setup.py  
/headers
    test_header.h
/source
    test_source.cpp
```

Here, Cython file `test.pxd` directly includes the `../source/test_source.cpp` which further includes the header `/header/test_header.h`.

The makefile does run and compile the first time. Unfortunately, after I made changes to `../header/test_header.h`, it appeared that `make` didn't notice those changes at all. (However, the changes made in `../source/test_source.cpp` were noticed by `make`.) I understand this is most likely a dependency issue. But, after reading some online tutorials I still don't quite understand how to properly set up this dependency chain.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this issue is more related to the Cython `setup.py` file and it has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674774/how-to-add-header-files-in-setup-py-so-dependencies-are-observed-when-building-t)